# Ember.js, Looping through two array's with {{each}} loops

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, csv, ember.js

I'm using Ember.js and I’m building a dynamic table. Essentially a user uploads a TSV file and I display the data in a table. However the format of these files are not uniform, they will be different every time, so I cannot hard code the column names. Right now I have an array of column names and I also have the array of objects with the data from the TSV file. Is it possible with Ember to use two {{each}} loops to display the data? My issue is in the second loop I cannot use dot notation or brackets with the second looping variable. Is there an ‘ember way’ solution to this common problem?

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        {{#each columns as |name|}}
            <th>{{name}}</th>  
        {{/each}}
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {{#each fileData as |data|}}
            <tr>
                {{#each columns as |name|}}
                    <td>{{data.name}}</td>  <!-- doesn't work -->
                    <td>{{data[name]}}</td> <!-- also doesn't work -->
                {{/each}}
            </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You'll probably need to use the get helper here, `{{get data name}}`.

https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/2.15/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers/methods/get?anchor=get

Comment: That worked, Perfect answer.

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeRoy Update your comments as answer

Comment: @kumkanillam done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to access the properties of an Ember object using a dynamic list. What you're looking for is the [get helper](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/2.15/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers/methods/get?anchor=get).

In this case:

```
{{#each fileData as |data|}}
  {{#each columns as |name|}}
    <td>{{get data name}}</td>
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```